# Text converts to String but not outputting full length in windows form tab

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms

The problem that I've got is that I'm creating a desktop application in Visual Studio 2019 and using Windows Form. I've got to the stage where I'm creating a tab but the name which I'm assigning it in nameOfSubjectInput and then outputting it to a string called subjectName.

From this it then should display the full name in the tab when created but it doesn't and it shows in the Debug.WriteLine(subjectName) which I've put in to see what the output is. What I'm trying to solve but to no success Googling etc is getting the full string to display but still stumped on how to get it to display.

The github for the project https://github.com/PeterSeatter/Dynamic-Grade-Calculator

[image of what the problem looks like in practice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64OOj.jpg)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    string subjectName;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void numberOfPapersInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        //only allows the input of whole numbers.
        if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) && (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void nameOfSubjectInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        subjectName = nameOfSubjectInput.Text;
    }

    private void numberOfPapersInput_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(numberOfPapersInput.Text))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            numberOfPapersInput.Focus();
            errorProviderPaperNumbers.SetError(numberOfPapersInput, "Please enter the number of papers!");
            MessageBox.Show(numberOfPapersInput, "Please enter the number of papers!");;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = false;
            errorProviderPaperNumbers.SetError(numberOfPapersInput, "");
        }
    }

    private void generateTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        TabPage newTab = new TabPage(subjectName);
        Debug.WriteLine(subjectName);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(newTab);
        Debug.WriteLine(numberOfPapersInput);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: okay @LarsTech I've put the whole project up on GitHub so no replication is required https://github.com/PeterSeatter/Dynamic-Grade-Calculator

Comment: @Peter That is not how Stack Overflow works; please read the [mre] page.

Comment: You are recording the subjectName in the KeyPress event: `subjectName = nameOfSubjectInput.Text;`  but the KeyPress hasn't finished processing, so `nameOfSubjectInput.Text` doesn't have the last character inputted yet.  You could write "This is my tab" and it would come out "This is my ta".

Comment: @LarsTech thanks that solved this issue